# Do HKLM registries take precedence over HKCU for system policies?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I can't seem to find anything definitive, as there are some sources that say:

> If an entry exists in both `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes` and `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes`, then the value of the entry in `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes` takes precedence.

However, I can't tell if this rule carries over to system policies; specifically, I am concerned about `DisableLockWorkstation` within:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
```

Which one of these would take precedence if both exist and are conflicting, and is there a general rule for this?

Comment: This sounds like [the XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: And why are you using the registry to do what you want? The registry is not a user tool.

Comment: @DaveWhite I am simply trying to find out which of those policies would take precedence if both exist and are conflicting - for the purposes of answering a question on another stack exchange. :)

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks! I don't have a windows machine available for testing just now, so I'll probably test it in a couple of days or so.

Comment: @nobody _(link updated to correct one & key tested)_ By default, `HKCU` should take precedence unless a system-level modification, such as a Group Policy, mandates system, not user, hives take precedence. After testing, unless it's explicitly set at the system level via Group Policy, removing user editing ACL from the `HKCU` key, etc., `HKCU` will be honored over `HKLM` _(simply adding the `HKLM` key doesn't cause precedence)_. While I don't have the time to provide specific links, this is likely covered on [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry).

Comment: @JW0914 You might as well as turn that into an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: @nobody As it sits, that's not acceptable as an answer to me, as I'd need to further research it and provide supporting definitive links from Microsoft Docs, which I don't have time to do and is why I answered in a comment. I'd also want to verify the Group Policy and ACL examples, as even though I'm 99% sure that's correct, I'd still want to verify it if putting it into an actual answer. Simply because I know `HKCU` generally takes precedence, without supporting information from Microsoft Docs, or other official Microsoft documentation, I can't put that into an answer.

Comment: @JW0914 Weird. I just tested this. It seems that `DisableLockWorkstation` in `HKLM` has absolutely no effect, even if it's equivalent does not exist in `HKCU`. That is not at all what I expected.

Comment: @nobody My hunch is it's not a valid `HKLM` key; even in `gpedit.msc`, it's listed under `User Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Ctrl+Alt+Del Options\Remove Lock Computer`. A definitive answer can likely be found in [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry), but requires time researching. For Windows versions lacking Group Policy [non-Pro/Enterprise], it can be enforced by adding it to each user's `HKU` hive, as well as the default hive [`HKU\.DEFAULT`] _(new users)_, since only `System`||`Administrators` have write access to `..\Policies\..`

Answer (score 6):

Qoting from Wikipedia
[Windows Registry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry#Root_keys):

> The HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (local machine-specific configuration data) and HKEY_CURRENT_USER (user-specific configuration data) nodes have a similar structure to each other; user applications typically look up their settings by first checking for them in "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Vendor's name\Application's name\Version\Setting name", and if the setting is not found, look instead in the same location under the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE key.
>
> However, the converse may apply for administrator-enforced policy settings where HKLM may take precedence over HKCU. The Windows Logo Program has specific requirements for where different types of user data may be stored, and that the concept of least privilege be followed so that administrator-level access is not required to use an application.

Unfortunately,
I don't think there is a definitive answer to the question,
so that it all depends on the program in question.

It seems as if user applications will prefer HKCU, while Windows will
prefer HKLM for policies that are not user-specific.
However, the rules are not set in concrete, and plenty of exceptions
may exist.

The Wikipedia link to the Windows Logo Program has elapsed,
but I managed to find
[Designed for Windows XP Application Specification](https://web.archive.org/web/20040829061226/http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=209e3d65-f0be-4eef-8602-73bb9bc29d54)
(archived article),
which pertains to the above-mentioned "Windows Logo Program",
containing the following rules
which in general support the above:

> **Using the Registry**
>
> Applications may also use the registry to store read/write application
> data and configuration files.
>
> - The HKCU registry hive is appropriate for storing small amounts of data (approximately 64K) and for policy settings that are per user.
> - Avoid writing to HKLM during runtime, because limited users have read-only access to the entire HKLM tree by default. In addition, HKLM
>   does not support roaming.
> - Larger, file-based data should be placed in the Application Data folder. For example, Internet Explorer’s Temporary Internet Cache is
>   stored within the user profile and not in the registry.
> - At installation time, the application must not store more than a total of 128K across HKCU and HKLM.  Note that HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT is
>   excluded.

This is the earliest document with guidelines on using the registry
that I could manage to find. I don't know how well these guidelines
were or are being followed.

Answer (score 3):

There is no iron rule here. Precedence depends wholy from programmers decicions therefore it differs between different systems and sometimes even different programs from the same developer.

As a rule of thumb, applications prefer HKCU as more specific. It's logical that if user have specific setting, its probably better for him than general setting. But ie. .\Run entries are first read from HKLM and many policies are prioritizing HKLM setting over HKCU.

Considering that `DisableLockWorkstation` is a policy, I would assume that HKLM will take priority in this case. But there is no way to tell that other than by test on a living system.